# Is "Und die Leute um mich herum auch, die lachen mir zu" correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

Shouldn't the construct of this sentence be as follow:

> Ich bekomme gute Laune, wenn ich aufs Rad steige. Und die Leute um mich herum auch, die mir lachen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original is correct, yours is not.

First, the verb is *zulachen*, not *lachen*.

Second, *die lachen mir zu*, is the main clause (note that the part before the comma does not have a verb), not a relative clause, hence the verb must be in second position.

Comment: I understand now ....the key answer and the point I was missing is that the second sentence: "die lachen mir zu" is not a relative clause but it is a main clause .... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking into a dictionary, you will find that *lachen* is an **intransitive** verb in German (i.e. one that cannot take an object).

Your construct "mir lachen" uses the pronoun "mir" as a dative object, so *must be wrong*.

Now go back to the dictionary and try and find "zulachen" (if your dictionary is any good, you'll find it like in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zulachen)). That is a transitive, separable verb that can take a dative object. So, what you wrote in your heading is correct.